# Is there a YouTube-like service that allows uploading a 100 thousand 5 second videos via an API?

Tags: youtube-api

YouTube's API documentation states that there is a 2000 video limit on uploads.

Since I doubt that YouTube would wave the limit (prior to being able to show we are a profitable partner to them), we need an alternative that allow thousands of very short video clips.

Comment: Why the heck would you want to upload **100,000** videos of **5 tiny seconds each?** That's a shitload of metadata per video, and no video will be meaningful by itself, will it? Consider merging some... and ask yourself if you really need ca. 138 hours.

Comment: A bit of explanation might be of help. This sounds like spamming or advertising of some sort which might hold back people from giving advise.

Comment: This is a great question for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ (a sister site of stackoverflow)

Comment: We are thinking of an application along the lines of golf swing analysis. Where each swing only takes a few seconds, but can be broken down separately for analysis. The video and professional's advice posted online for the client to view. If we break the video apart per swing, the client can select per club (Driver vs pitching wedge) and watch one particular swing multiple times without rewinding.

Answer (score 0):

[Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/) might allow this (if the size of the videos is reasonable). They work on a total storage basis.

Comment: Unfortunately, Vimeo's signup page states that it is for "Noncommercial use only". As it would be nice to turn a profit, we may run into issues with their policy.

Comment: I guess the rules that Vimeo & Youtube impose are because one day they want to turn a profit too...  :P  (I don't know about Vimeo, but Youtube hasn't made a profit ever, and only survives because Google's other divisions make a lot of profit.)